# GNU as: Escape symbol names in intel_syntax

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

With GNU as `.intel_syntax`, some identifiers apparently become keywords, and writing e.g.

```
call and
```

to invoke a function called `and` results in

```
Error: invalid use of operator "and"
```

How do you circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the answer seems to be:

## This is not possible. Use AT&T syntax.

Looking at the GAS sources, `config/tc-i386-intel.c` lines 136ff are pretty clear about this.

Some GNU developer considered completely disabling some symbol names to be a reasonable way of introducing named operators. Such a small bad design decision cost me and probably many other unfortunate users a whole afternoon. Don't be that guy.

Comment: Perhaps they were thinking that `and` is a C++ keyword so C++ compiler output wouldn't use it as a function name.  Of course they were wrong, C doesn't have that as a keyword and there are lots of other relevant languages, not to mention hand-written asm.  Anyway, it's easy to craft a C source file that leads to `gcc -masm=intel -c` feeding `as` with assembly it chokes on: https://godbolt.org/z/dj1annYcn  Even `call and@PLT` doesn't help, nor does putting it in double-quotes